# Assume that n^2 is divisible by 3. Prove that n^2 is divisible by 9.

Tags: proof-writing

I'm trying to write a simple, informal proof to this problem. I know it would likely be simpler to tackle by showing a proof by contraposition, but I'm being asked specifically to write a proof by either contradiction or cases.

In proof by contraposition I think it might look something like this:

Let n be an integer.
 If n^2 is not divisible by 9, there is no integer k such that n^2 = 9k. 
 9k = 3(3k). 
 Let 3k = m, where m is an integer.
Then there is no integer m such that n^2 = 3m. 
 Therefore n^2 is not divisible by 3. 
Therefore if n^2 is not divisible by 9, it is not divisible by 3. 
Therefore if n^2 is divisible by 3, it is divisible by 9.

But I'm not sure how you would move from that to proof by contradiction. For proof by contradiction I think you would start out by assuming that n^2 is not divisible by 9 and demonstrating that this creates a contradiction with n^2 being divisible by 3, but I am not sure.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You could assume $n^2$ is divisible by 3 as a given, and then assume $n^2$ is not divisible by 9 to find the contradiction.

Comment: I see that, but it isn't clear to me how I'd write that out in order to show a contradiction.

Comment: @MariahLynn Contraposition would not be a natural choice to prove this, since the direct proof is so straightforward ([Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma)).

Comment: Your proof is wrong.  You show there is no $m$ of the form $3k$ such that $n^2 = 3m$, but that doesn't say there is no such integer $m$ at all.

Comment: @dxiv True! I didn't think of direct proof haha (silly), but either way I unfortunately can't use it here.

Answer (score 1):

Let the prime factorization of n be
$$
n=p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}} p_{2}^{\alpha_{2}} \cdots p_{m}^{\alpha_{m}},
$$
then $$
\begin{array}{rl}
\quad n^{2} & =p_{1}^{2 \alpha_{1}} p_{2}^{2 \alpha_{2}} \ldots p_{m}^{2 \alpha_{m}} \\
3 \mid n^2& \Rightarrow  3 \mid p_{1}^{2 \alpha_{1}} \cdot p_{2}^{2\alpha_{2}} \ldots p_{m}^{2\alpha_{m}} \\
& \Rightarrow 3 \mid p_{i} \quad \exists i \in \{1,2,3, \cdots, m\} \\
& \Rightarrow 3^{2} \mid p_{i}^{2} \\
& \Rightarrow 9 \mid p_{i}^{2 \alpha_{i}} \\
& \Rightarrow 9 \mid n^{2}
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $n^2$ is not divisible by 9, then there does not exist a $k$ such that $n^2 = 9 k^2 = (3k)^2$, and so there does not exist an $n = 3k$ (due to 3 being prime and the fundamental theorem of arithmetic). Therefore, $n$ cannot be divisible by 3.

This implies that $n^2$ is not divisible by 3. Contradiction.

Comment: You haven't shown that $n^2$ divisible by $3$ implies $n$ divisible by $3$.  This could be done either by cases ($n \equiv 1$ or $2 \mod 3$) or using unique factorization (the fundamental theorem of arithmetic).

Answer (score 0):

if $\frac{n^2}{9} = (\frac{n}{3})^2$ not an integer, then $\frac{n}{3}$ not an integer. But $3 | n^2 \implies 3 | n$.

Comment: "$3 \mid n^2 \implies 3 \mid n$" $\;-\;$ This is indeed true, but you have to prove it, otherwise it's just assuming something equivalent to what you set out to prove.

Comment: I was assuming we can use if $p | ab$, either $p|a$ or $p|b$ or $p$ divides both.

Comment: You need to at least state that explicitly. And, once you do, the entire proof can be reduced to $\,3 \mid n^2 \implies 3 \mid n \implies 3^2 \mid n^2\,$.